# Find out Kafka Message version

Tags: apache-kafka, version, message

the default `server.properties` on `0.10.1.1` Broker doesn't define the `log.message.format.version` explicitly. Even though it is supposed to be same Kafka API Version; is there a way to find it out?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not defined explicitely in the broker properties file, then `log.message.format.version` will match the broker version.

You can see that from the configuration documentation for each release. For example for 0.10.1.1, it is `0.10.1-IV2` according to the [0.10.1 docs](http://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#brokerconfigs).

One way to double check is to look at the broker logs. When starting up, brokers dump their configuration including settings that have not be overriden in the properties file.

That should include `log.message.format.version=0.10.1-IV2` in your case.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I saw that, but is there anyway to know for sure it is *the* version at work?

Comment: We are migrating to higher broker version (`0.10.1.1` -> `2.0.X`) to different new machines. I am trying to figure out, if I copy the messages from Old to New Machines with Higher Broker versions, if that going to work? Or what else is the way? I would need to keep the message Ordering. Any ideas please?

Comment: Thanks, will check and accept. Would it be possible to help me on my 2nd comment? I can create a question, if you want me to?

Comment: Your second comment is a whole different question. I'm afraid, you've not put enough details explaining what you're trying to do for me to reply accurately. Feel free to submit another question with more details

Comment: Thanks Mike. posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667042/kafka-message-migration